# Why is that when I do an if code in PHP i get a value

Tags: php

I set an if in php code and instead of it passing and allowing my data if it equals a value. It instead returns my value back. Here is the code:

```
   if(getDataSQL("value", "configuration", "website_chatbox") == 'Active') { 

       echo "Hello world";

   }
```

Instead of getting my code it instead outputs the value Active.

```
   Active
```

Why is my code not working?

Comment: Show the code for `getDataSQL()`

Comment: I think getDataSQL has an `echo Active` inside it, pretty sure

Comment: Sounds like `getDataSQL` is echoing the value instead of returning it.

Comment: `ctrl F` `echo 'Active';` replace by `return 'Active';` as Barmar said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your function is saying something like:

```
echo $your_variable;
```

when you should really do this:

```
return $your_variable;
```

You see the return statement is what you need for the if statement to evaluate its response.

Comment: thanks I had it that way before and somehow it was not working.....whatever it works now...

Comment: pleased I could help :)